# Connect multiple Serialports from Arduino with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, arduino, serial-port

I'm having trouble connecting 4 arduinos using serialports and NodeJs.
When I connect all the ports only one is actually working and collecting the data message while all the others are ignored.

If I declare the serial ports separately they all work fine so the problem is not the Arduino code.

Here's how i declare all the serialports:

```
// Load HTTP module to create server, handle requests and send back static files (html, css, js)
const http = require('http');
// Load file system module to load files from computer
const fs = require('fs');
// Load path module to read paths from urls
const path = require('path');

// Load serialport module to communicate with arduino
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
// Open up connection with Arduino board
const serial = new SerialPort('/dev/cu.usbserial-1411140', {
        baudRate: 115200
    }, function() {
        console.log('1411140 ready');
})

const SerialPort1 = require('serialport');
const serial1 = new SerialPort1('/dev/cu.usbserial-141120', {
        baudRate: 115200
    }, function() {
        console.log('141120 ready');
})

const SerialPort2 = require('serialport');
const serial2 = new SerialPort2('/dev/cu.usbmodem-1411301', {
        baudRate: 115200
    }, function() {
        console.log('1411301 ready');
})

const SerialPort3 = require('serialport');
const serial3 = new SerialPort3('/dev/cu.usbserial-1411130', {
        baudRate: 115200
    }, function() {
        console.log('1411130 ready');
})

// Define port on which the webpage will be served from
const port = 8080;
```

This is how i read the arduino data

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
// do stuff when a client connects
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a new client connected');
    // let the client know that it's connected
    socket.emit('greetings', 'You are now connected to the server through Socket IO');

    // when receiving data from Arduino, tell the client what to do accordingly
    serial.on('data', forwardMessage);


    // log if an user disconnects
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
        // remove listener from Node EventEmitter
        serial.removeListener('data', forwardMessage);
    });

    function forwardMessage(data) {
        let message = data.toString().replace(/\n*/, '');
        //riceve messaggi dal device corrispondente. Attenzione al nome messo anche sul codice Arduino
        if (message.includes('Coinv')) {
            socket.emit('CoinvChange', message.substring(7));
        }
        if (message.includes('Impor')) {
            socket.emit('ImporChange', message.substring(7));
        }
        if (message.includes('Piace')) {
            socket.emit('PiaceChange', message.substring(7));
        }
        if (message.includes('Cresc')) {
            socket.emit('CrescChange', message.substring(7));
        }
        if (message.includes('Press')) {
            socket.emit('PressChange', message.substring(7));
        }
    }
});
```

And finally this is how i use the message

```
const socket = io();

// log on browser console when socket is connected to server
socket.on('greetings', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});

// Caricamento Petali
socket.on('CoinvChange', (message) => {
  console.log('coinv');

  if(message<=6){
    getFlowerObject ("petali", 1);
  }

  if(message>7 && message <=9) {
    getFlowerObject ("petali", 2);
  }

  if(message>12) {
    getFlowerObject ("petali", 3);
  }
});

// Caricamento Sepali
socket.on('ImporChange', (message) => {
  console.log('Impor');

  if(message<=2){
    getFlowerObject ("sepali", 1);
  }

  if(message>3 && message <=7) {
    getFlowerObject ("sepali", 2);
  }

  if(message>8) {
    getFlowerObject ("sepali", 3);
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the second snipped, you call just `serial.on('data', forwardMessage);`, and `serial` just refers to the firt one.
If you want to interact with the other ones, you have to call the same method also on `serial1`, `serial2` and `serial3`, which you never use, instead.

As a sidenote, it's enugh to use `const SerialPort = require('serialport');` just at the beginning (of the first snippet), then you can do

```
const serial1 = new SerialPort(...)
...
const serial2 = new SerialPort(...)
...
```